# How can I add components into fxml scene using code

Tags: javafx

I am using `JavaFX` and a scene is loaded by `fxml` file.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent rootNode = (Parent) loader.load(fxmlFile);
setScene(new Scene(rootNode));
stage.setScene(scene);
```

How can I add `components` into this `scene`? For example How can I add a `button` using code into this `scene`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider you have `borderPane` as the `root` element of the FXML. Now you can go on as this :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent rootNode = (Parent) loader.load(fxmlFile);
Button button = new Button();
((BorderPane) rootNode).setCenter(button);
setScene(new Scene(rootNode));
stage.setScene(scene);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I edit scene components when scene is created and after stage.show() method?